# Groovy 'No signature of method' running Closure against delegate

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a closure that's executed against another Groovy object as the delegate. I can do:

```
foo {
    bar {
        major = 1
    }
}
```

but when I do:

```
foo {
    bar {
        major 1
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
> No signature of method: my.Bar.major() is applicable for argument types (java.lang.Integer) values: [1]
Possible solutions: setMajor(java.lang.Integer), getMajor(), wait(), any(), setMajor(java.lang.String), wait(long)
```

Bar looks something like:

```
class Bar {
    Integer major
    Integer getMajor() { return this.major }
    def setMajor(Integer val) { this.major = val }
}
```

I thought Groovy made getters/setters transparent when dealing with property references and that referring to `bar.major` was the same as `bar.get/setMajor()`. Am I understanding this wrong, or does the meta class lookup route differ when you throw `Closure` delegates into the mix? The resolution strategy is `DELEGATE_FIRST`.

For more context: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/groovy-no-signature-of-method-running-closure-against-delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would have to add also `void major(Integer val)`. `major = 1` is groovy-short for `setMajor(1)` while `major 1` is short for `major(1)`. (see [Section *Optional parenthesis*](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Statements))

> #### Optional parenthesis
>
> Method calls in Groovy can omit the parenthesis if there is at least one parameter and there is no ambiguity.
>
> ```
> println "Hello world"
> System.out.println "Nice cheese Gromit!"
> ```

E.g.:

```
class X {
    Integer major
    void major(Integer m) { major = m }
}

def x = new X()
x.major = 1 // x.setMajor(1)
assert x.major==1 // x.getMajor()==1
x.major 2 // x.major(2)
assert x.major==2
```

If you need this behaviour alot, you can add a `methodMissing` for this case.  E.g.:

```
class X {
    Integer major
    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        if (this.hasProperty(name) && args.size()==1) {
            this."$name" = args[0]
        } else {
            throw new MissingMethodException(name, this.class, args)
        }
    }
}

def x = new X()
x.major = 1
assert x.major==1
x.major 2
assert x.major==2
```

Comment: So basically I just don't understand how the property references work. Is there any thorough doc on this? I've read the [official Groovy-bean docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans) and was no lead to this conclusion.

Comment: all about the fields is a good read.  but here applies [Optional parenthesis](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Statements)

Comment: Yeah I get that it's a method call, thanks (= I just thought that the property references extended to method calls. I thought wrong.