# Nested object inside custom plugin extension

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm developing a custom Gradle plugin and I want to define a configuration closure (plugin extension) like this:

```
myplugin {
   property1 'value'

   property2 {
     a1 'hello'
     a2 'bye'
   }
}
```

I have this classes:

```
public class MyPluginExtension { //root extension

    String property1;
    Property2 peroperty2;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Property2 {
    String a1;
    String a2;
    //getters and setters
}
```

And, in the plugin project, I create the extension this way:

```
project.getExtensions().create("myplugin", MyPluginExtension.class);
```

But in my client project, when I apply and configure the plugin like shown above, I get this error:

> Gradle DSL method not found: 'property2()'

How can I define the `property2` closure in my `MyPluginExtension` class?

**EDIT**

I have tried this:

```
 public class MyPluginExtension { //root extension

    String property1;
    Property2 peroperty2;

        //getters and setters

    public void property2(Closure c) {
        c.setResolveStrategy(Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST);
        c.setDelegate(property2);
        c.call();
    }
}
```

But now I get this error:

> Gradle DSL method not found: a1()

It can't resolve nested closure fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to utilize a `Closure` with delegate set to particular object:

```
class SamplePlugin implements Plugin {
   void apply(Object p) {
      p.extensions.create("e", MyPluginExtension)
   }
}

class MyPluginExtension { 

    Property2 property2 = new Property2()
    String property1

    def property2(Closure c) {
      c.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
      c.delegate = property2
      c()
    }
}

class Property2 {
    String a1
    String a2

    def a1(a1) {
      this.a1 = a1
    }

    def a2(a2) {
      this.a2 = a2
    }
}

apply plugin: SamplePlugin

e {
   property1 'lol'
   property2 {
      a1 'lol2'
      a2 'lol3'
   }
}

println e.property1
println e.property2.a1
```

Please also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100232/groovy-no-signature-of-method-running-closure-against-delegate) why additional methods are needed. And [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/33606861) you can find a working demo that is implemented in java.

Comment: Thanks. What about if I using Java instead of Groovy?

Comment: Just define it all using java syntax. Should work as well.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it and seems solved but now it can't resolve nested closure fields. Look at my edit.

Comment: See my answer, there's a method called `a1` in my code.

Comment: @bigdestroyer, you need to add: `void a1(String a1) { this.a1 = a1; }` method.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now